# How to send data/event to Fragment that may be still being initialized?

Tags: android, events, android-activity, fragment

My scenario is:

- I have an `Activity` that triggers events and send them to a `Fragment`.
- I have a `Fragment` that receives events and show the events' data in a `View`.

The first time I trigger an event, I initialize the `Fragment` and the `View`, and display the first event info.

I may have two or more events being triggered simultaneously. Once I send the event to the Fragment, I have a boolean that tells me whether it's the first event, so for the next events I should just append the info to the `View` in the `Fragment`.

**Problem**: my second event is triggered, I should append this data to the `View`. However, the `Fragment` is still being initialized, and there's actually a set delay to show this `View`.

How should I handle it?

What I thought was to add a `while (! myView.isReady) { } //send event`, but might not be that correct or efficient.

Any thoughts are very appreciated!

Comment: In what way are you "passing" those events to your `Fragment`?

Comment: Say I have a new event like "Alice texted you" and then "Bob texted you," I want to "pass" this info to this Fragment that will have a temporary View showing both notifications. It's like an internal notification.

Comment: I understand the concept, but in what way exactly? You're using some some sort of listener, method call, event bus? How?

Comment: Got your question. Actually it's a background service that triggers events based on my location. I broadcast the event from the service to my Activity, which 'passes' it to my current Fragment.

Comment: I already made it work  with the strategy mentioned. I'll post my code later